# Python Import Error - no module named

Tags: python, import, gunicorn

So I've inherited a flask project. When I run a command to check configuration, an ImportErrror is thrown, despite the package being installed:

```
jakub@jakub-S300CA:~/Desktop/rankingbrands$ pip install configparser
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): configparser in /home/jakub/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
jakub@jakub-S300CA:~/Desktop/rankingbrands$ gunicorn --check-config rankingbrands

Error while loading the application:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 144, in run
self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 365, in import_app
__import__(module)
  File "/home/jakub/Desktop/rankingbrands/rankingbrands/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
import configparser
ImportError: No module named configparser
jakub@jakub-S300CA:~/Desktop/rankingbrands$ gunicorn --check-config rankingbrands
```

What seems to be the problem? I thought this error was thrown only when I haven't imported the package

Comment: Those messages show that pip is referencing Python 3.5 but gunicorn is using Python 2.7.

Comment: Note, however, that module is in the standard library in both versions; there is no need to install it. But in 2.7 it's called ConfigParser.

Comment: any idea why is python 2 being used by the modules and how to change it? I have set my python version to be 3                                                      - jakub@jakub-S300CA:~/Desktop/rankingbrands$ python --version
Python 3.4.3+, and also chose it to be the interpreter in my IDE.

Comment: This might be because I switched to linux a day ago and I'm still incredibly confused by it :)